# P-value correction for multiple comparisons using Mann-Whitney test (using R)

Tags: r, p-value, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have one question regarding the adjusted p-value for multiple comparison using Mann-Whitney test.

The data structure that I am dealing with is something like this:

- Two groups to compare: Group 1 vs Group 2 (NOT pairwise)
- Each group having only 6 patients
- 200 proteins levels (continuous) were observed

[image]

**Goal: 

What I want to obtain is a list of proteins that are significantly different between Group 1 and Group 2.**

If each group has a fairly large number of patients, then I would use t-test using an adjusted p-value. However, because we have only 6 patients, I would like to use the nonparametric test, Mann-Whitney test. 
I think I need to use the adjusted p-value in this case as well. However, I was not able to find how to correct p-value for the nonparametric case and an appropriate function in R.

**So my question is:

1. Should I use the adjusted p-value?
2. If so, is there any formula or built-in function in R that can do it??**

Looking forward to hearing from you all!

Comment: Adjustments to p-values do not care what test generated the p-value. You can do the adjustments as if the p-values came from the t-test. // I question the wisdom of going with a nonparametric test because of the small sample size. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the quick reply, Dave! I thought that a nonparametric test is appropriate because of the non-normality of the data. I have only 6 data points for each  group, so when it comes to seeing the histogram, it does not look like normally distributed. Even in this case, do you think that I can use a t-test?

Comment: It is hard to judge normality with just six points. I just ran simulations where I drew from a normal distribution via `set.seed(2021); N <- 6; x <- rnorm(N); hist(x)` in R, and the histogram looked non-normal. Ditto for seeds $202$, $20$, and $2$. Do you have some theoretical reason to expect normal data? // What do you do with the $200$ proteins?

Comment: @Dave There is no theoretical background to expect normal data. If I can standardize the 6 data points (e.g., mean 0, var 1), then will it be OK to use a  t-test even with only 6 subjects in each group?

Comment: Standardization has nothing to do with an assumption of normality. Also, consider what happens if you standardize each group to have a mean of $0$ and a variance of $1$.

Comment: @Dave hmmm. OK. If there is no reason to assume that the data is normally distributed and the observed data cannot prove anything about the normality due to a small sample size (which is my case), then the nonparametric test is the most appropriate, right?

Comment: I think you might be in a tough spot with so few samples, but I want to know what you do with those $200$ proteins.

Comment: @rudgus51998 your problem will be a lack of available significance levels. In a 6 vs 6 Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney, the lowest attainable two-tailed significance level is 0.0021645. If you were to do say a Bonferroni adjustment with 200 tests from a 5% significance level, your test-wise significance level would be set at less than one eighth of that, and so you could ***never reject***, no matter how different your samples were. My suggestion is to seek a better parametric model for whatever your response variable is (but don't use your present data to choose that model).

Comment: Many people seem to think "normal or nothing". This is a puzzling dichotomy. There's an infinity of possible distributional models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are research questions in astronomy that you can answer with your naked eyes, for some you need a giant telescope. In biology, there are research questions for which you just need more than 6 subjects in a group.

In general, it doesn't matter if a p-value is computed from a parametric or non-parametric model, the same correction methods can be used. As was already pointer out in the comments, the smallest p-value you can get with Mannthe -Whitney test is 0.002, if all subjects from one group have a higher protein level than all subjects from the other group. So with Bonferroni correction(non recommended), you cannot find any significant result. There are better correction or modeling approaches, but I do not think they can help you a lot unless you expect huge effects on many proteins.

In general, you can try to use better correction methods than Bonferroni that takes into account that various variables are correlated, you can use something like a MANOVA instead of many independent tests, you can try to limit the number of tests you are going to perform by either selecting only a few proteins based on your prior knowledge or averaging some proteins together or doing some other data reduction techniques. All these methods are probably going to hit their limits with your sample size. Another option is to use a hierarchical Bayesian model, but that is outside of my expertise.